# Ruby on Rails authentication without user name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In all of my Rails applications I have a User model with `name`, `email` and `password` attributes (among others).

This seems to be the standard approach when building Rails apps.

The more Rails apps I build, the more I begin to wonder why the `User.name` is even necessary.

Wouldn't it be easier to just omit the user name everywhere right from the start?

From a user perspective, the sign up process will become easier. Instead of filling in four fields (`username`, `email`, `password`, and `password confirmation`), the user will have to fill in only three.

According to some usability experts this might increase the number of sign ups.

In addition to that, users will also have to remember *less* data, i.e. only their email address (which most people have memorized anyway).

So what might be negative implications of this approach?

I couldn't think of any so far.

Comment: what if the user don't have an email ? or he just don't want to use email for your app ? or if he prefer username than lengthy email ?

Comment: An `email address` is definitely required in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `username` is "standart" approach with rails apps. In fact, [devise's](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) vanilla approach is using only email on models.

However, being able to accept `username` **or**  `email` has many other advantages. You may have other scenarios where users do not register at all. I mean, perhaps you are also creating accounts for users without any registration and you don't know their emails, if so using email will not be an option.

In some applications, we use more then 3 authentication strategies. Some users do not have a username or email at all..

In short, i think it really depends on your scenarios. But i am sure that using both email **and** username is not a rails convention.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make emails from your app personalized, maybe with greetings such as `Dear <%= username %>.

This doesn't mean you have to put `name` as one of the sign-up fields. You can put in the update form only, when the user edits their profile. Then you can make the `edit_user_registration_path` the `after_sign_up_path_for` devise.

Answer (score 1):

If the main goal is a frictionless signup process then an OAUTH strategy would be the best way to go (4 fields of info down to two clicks), however you may want to collect the user info at a later time for a more personalized feel depending on what info you can capture from the callback.